# java tab panels adding and removing

Tags: java, tabs, jpanel

i have a jpanel (jpanel A) with a button and when pressed 
will open a tab jpanel (example 1)

[image]

so when you press the button you end up with 2 tabs jpanel A and example 1.

the original japanel is now a tabbed panel

when i delete example 1 i am left with jpanel A however this panel is in a tab
.
[image]
is there a way that i can revert back to the original  jpanel when the other jpanel (example 1) is deleted.

[image]

Comment: can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(null);
    panel2.setLayout(null);
    tabbedPane.add("aaa", panel1);
    panel1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
    tabbedPane.add("bbbb", panel2);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
    Dimension sc = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int wid = sc.width/2;``
    int hig = sc.height/2;
    tabbedPane.setSize(wid, hig);
    add(tabbedPane);
```

}